# Hadoop preinstalled example Jars

Tags: hadoop, error-handling, terminal

I just successfully set up Hadoop on my local machines. I am following one of the examples in a popular book I just bought. I am trying to get a list of all hadoop examples that comes with installation. I type the following command to do so:

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-*-examples.jar
```

Once I enter this I am supposed to get a list of Hadoop examples right? However all I see is this error message:

```
Not a valid JAR: /home/user/hadoop/hadoop-*-examples.jar
```

How do I solve this problem? Is it just a simple permission issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably configuration issue or usage of invalid file paths.

Most probably the name of hadoop-*-examples.jar is not correct because in my version of Hadoop (1.0.0) file name is  hadoop-examples-1.0.0.jar.

So I have run following command to list all examples and it works like charm:

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-*.jar 

An example program must be given as the first argument.
Valid program names are:
  aggregatewordcount: An Aggregate based map/reduce program that counts the words in the input files.
  aggregatewordhist: An Aggregate based map/reduce program that computes the histogram of the words in the input files.
  dbcount: An example job that count the pageview counts from a database.
  grep: A map/reduce program that counts the matches of a regex in the input.
  join: A job that effects a join over sorted, equally partitioned datasets
  multifilewc: A job that counts words from several files.
  pentomino: A map/reduce tile laying program to find solutions to pentomino problems.
  pi: A map/reduce program that estimates Pi using monte-carlo method.
  randomtextwriter: A map/reduce program that writes 10GB of random textual data per node.
  randomwriter: A map/reduce program that writes 10GB of random data per node.
  secondarysort: An example defining a secondary sort to the reduce.
  sleep: A job that sleeps at each map and reduce task.
  sort: A map/reduce program that sorts the data written by the random writer.
  sudoku: A sudoku solver.
  teragen: Generate data for the terasort
  terasort: Run the terasort
  teravalidate: Checking results of terasort
  wordcount: A map/reduce program that counts the words in the input files.
```

Also if I use same file name pattern as You I got error:

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-*examples.jar 

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error opening job jar: hadoop-*examples.jar
```

HTH

Comment: There was something wrong with my setup, I uninstalled hadoop and reinstalled it again. It fixed the issue. SOme of the online tutorials I followed instructed to make lot of configuration changes in config files which was not necessary for the tutorial I am following....

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the class name of the jar file which you want to use:

```
hadoop jar pathtojarfile classname arg1 arg2 ..
```

Example:

```
hadoop jar example.jar wordcount inputPath outputPath
```

Answer (score 0):

@Anup. The full / relative path to the jar file is required.

In your case it might be /home/user/hadoop/share/hadoop-*-examples.jar

The complete command from hadoop's directory might be

/home/user/hadoop/bin/hadoop /home/user/hadoop/share/hadoop-*-examples.jar

(I used absolute full paths there, but you can use relative paths).

Answer (score 0):

you will find the jar in `$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-*-examples*.jar`